# Create new array for each value separated by comma in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

> **input string:** "abc def, ghi jkl, mnopq"
>  **Desired Output Arrays:**
> ["abc","def"] ["ghi", "jkl"] ["mnopq"]

The input can be any combination of phrases separated by spaces, those phrases are then separated by commas. I need to make a new array for each input string which is followed by a comma. When those arrays are created they have to be split by " ".

Below is the code to split the string into array values using a comma as a separator:

```js
str = "abc def, ghi jkl, mnopq";     
const commaSeparatedArray = this.str.split(',').filter(s => s.slice(-1) !== ' ');

console.log(commaSeparatedArray);
```

Not sure if the next step to take here is a for or while loop for such actions or a javascript prototype?

Link to stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbdae5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 5):

The following gives you an array of array. If something similar you are looking for.

```js
var s = "abc def, ghi jkl, mnopq";
var result = s.split(',').map(a=>a.trim().split(' '));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice idea with `trim()` 

Comment: @PramodMali Thanks, great stuff. If you don't mind my asking how would i iterate through both inner and outer arrays say to console log each string seperately. I have tried: result.forEach(a=>console.log(a));

Comment: @rkras, you can flatten the result array using `Array.prototype.flat()` and loop over. i.e `result.flat().forEach(a=>console.log(a)`. For reference on flat() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 2):

```js
str = "abc def, ghi jkl, mnopq";

//you need to again split and filter out the empty string to get the desired output.

const commaSeparatedArray = this.str.split(',').map(item => {
  const d = item.split(' ').filter(i => i);
  return [...d]
})
console.log(commaSeparatedArray)
```

Comment: What's the `filter` for?

Comment: string has an extra space so when we use split it is giving an empty string and to avoid that I have used filter.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just want to do two rounds of splitting

```js
const str = "abc def, ghi jkl, mnopq";

const result = str.split(/,\s*/).map(substr => substr.split(/\s+/))

console.info(result)
```

That is

1. Split the string on comma + zero-or-more spaces
2. Then map each entry to another array by splitting that string on whitespace

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = "abc def, ghi jkl, mnopq";

const commaSeparatedArray = str.split(",");

const result = commaSeparatedArray.reduce((acc, stringWithspaces) => {
  return [...acc, stringWithspaces.split(" ").filter(string=> string)];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var str = "abc def, ghi jkl, mnopq";
var res = str.split(', ').map(x => x.split(' '));
console.log(res);
```